# Floating point multiplication overflow

Tags: c, algorithm, floating-point, precision, multiplication

I have the rules below for floating point multiplication.

My question is how can I know when E is out of range to know it's overflow?

I know that if the result is normalized we can apply E = exp - bias, and if it is de-normalized, E = 1 - bias. Based on exp, I know it's normalized or de-normalized so I can calculate the maximum value of E but in this case, I don't have exp yet, I can't calculate the range of E so how can I know if an overflow occurs or not?

Comment: The "range of E" to compare against is a constant based on your floating point format -- though out of range might be overflow (too large) or underflow (too negative), and for underflow you can convert to denormal.

Comment: Post text as text to add usefulness.

Comment: Note that while most cases of overflow *are* detected by comparing the sum of factor exponents to the range, re-normalisation of the mantissa may bring *E* back to the maximum allowed *if* the sum was too large by 1.

Comment: Note that the algorithm given is incomplete or incorrect: Rounding M could cause it to increase to 2. If it does, an adjustment must be performed by shifting M right one bit and increasing E by one. So overflow must be tested after rounding.

Comment: Your question hints that you might know the maximum value of *exp* (the encoding of an exponent, with bias). If so, then you know the maximum value of *E* (the true exponent, without bias). It is simply the maximum value of *exp* minus the bias.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the maximum range of anything, then you can't know if it will/won't overflow (or cause underflow).

However:

- if you assume that output has the same range as input/s, then you can assume something can't overflow. For example, consider "E1+E2 = 10 + (-1) = 9" where you say it can't overflow because 9 is between 10 and -1.
- for things like homework and uni assignments, whenever necessary information is missing you can assume whatever you like and state your assumption/s (e.g. "*I've assumed that this is IEEE double floating point where the exponent field is 8 bits with a bias of 128, and therefore has the range is -128 to +127*"); and then claim that the exponent will/won't overflow if your assumption is correct.
- for real software, you can find out what the range is (e.g. by checking `float.h`).